# PHP : load xml file and get node value

Tags: php, xml

My xml file is like below..

```
<CA>
  <student>
    <name>james</name>
    <seat>A2</seat>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>Asada</name>
    <seat>M13</seat>
  </student>
</CA>
```

And I want to approach "seat" node's value "A2"and "M13" using PHP.

```
$root = $xml->documentElement;
$current = $root->firstChild;
$test = $current->firstChild;
```

I can access "name" node using above code.
How can I access "seat" node?

Answer (score 4):

you can use XPath for that:

```
$xml = <<<END
<CA>
  <student>
  <name>james</name>
  <seat>A2</seat>
  </student>
  <student>
  <name>Asada</name>
  <seat>M13</seat>
  </student>
</CA> 
END;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entry = $xpath->query("//CA/student/seat");
foreach($entry as $ent){
  echo $ent->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleXML for that:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlContents);
foreach($xml->student as $student) {
    echo (string)$student->seat."\n";
}
```